# How to make animation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, animation

I want to add something to my project that is similar to a *Mortal Kombat* intro, and it will be called "Sonya v.s Scorpion". I tried to create it using Flash CS5. There is an animation going from left side to middle, another one from right side to middle, and "V.s" in the center.

I researched Javascript, but I don't know how to animate it... I can prepare it with Flash, but it makes website the slower. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not graphics artists.

Comment: You can use Canvas for this purpose. Make a canvas element and put there 2 sprites (images): scorpion and sonya. With canvas API you will be able to move it using JavaScript. If you master it you will be able to create good animation and even games. Good luck.

Comment: Thnx so much Lends..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Canvas for this purpose. Make a canvas element and put there 2 sprites (images): Scorpion and Sonya. With canvas API you will be able to animate it using JavaScript.

Check this link, it should help you a lot. There is a lot of examples. http://www.williammalone.com/articles/